# Error "Cannot read property 'indexedOptions' " when removing Company field (Remove checkout field)

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, plugin, component

I need to remove Company field from checkout page. I am trying to follow this tutorials ["Remove a component"](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html). But I am getting next Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexedOptions' of undefined(…) region.js:59
```

My Plugins file is:

```
public function aroundProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject, \Closure $proceed, $jsLayout) {
    unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['company']);
    return $jsLayout;
}
```

**Can anyone explain me please what i am doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in this page https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4425

And the working code is:

```
public function aroundProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject, \Closure $proceed, $jsLayout) {
    $ret = $proceed($jsLayout);
    unset($ret['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['company']);
    return $ret;
}
```

From this [plugin documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) I found also the problem: **"It is also worth noting that you are responsible for forwarding the arguments from the plugin to the proceed callable."** 
I add the the plugin function signature from @Aaron Allen answer to my [previous post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148740/error-in-remove-a-component-plugin-tutorial)  so it would be more clearer to anyone who would be needing it.

```
function aroundMethod ($subject, \Closure $proceed, $arg1, $arg2, etc...)
```