# Magento 2 - Stuck Checkout loader and Javascript error

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript

I recently upgraded from Magento 2.0.7 to Magento 2.1.2

After the upgrade, I keep running into this issue with a stuck checkout loader and the following javascript error message when I begin the checkout process:

> region.js:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexedOptions'
>   of undefined

I have cleared cache, static-content, and so forth with no avail on fixing the problem. Not sure how to go about fixing this issue.

I attached an image of what is happening, and a screen grab of the javascript error presented by the console on the browser.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How have you modified your shops checkout page? Have you use modules or theme? Can you turn them off and that may be  narrows down the source of the problem - it is first thing to do at least when debbuging wp page.

Answer (score 0):

From your error may be you have override

`Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor`

in your module check this question it will help you and add code of your override file.

[Error “Cannot read property 'indexedOptions' ” when removing Company field (Remove checkout field)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148776/error-cannot-read-property-indexedoptions-when-removing-company-field-remo)